# How to get timezone by IP

Tags: php, timezone, timezone-offset

I have a registration by which i can get the IP address of user who registers.

I want to get the timezone of user by his IP address.

Like in jquery we can get like this 
[Timezone in jquery](http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/)

How can i do it in PHP.

Comment: Similar, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743505/how-to-get-time-zone-through-ip-address-in-php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use GeoIP based services http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php

Or

You can use online services that gives timezone of the IP that you supply in request

i.e.

```
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation&template=php3.txt&IpAddress=94.55.180.139'); 
echo $tags['timezone'];
```