# How to get the current time/timezone of the user visiting my website?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, zend-framework

I am working on an application which utilizes PHP (Zend Framework) and JavaScript (jQuery).

I'm trying to get the current time of the user visiting the site. Is this possible? How can this be done?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630321/how-do-you-retrieve-the-client-users-time-zone-for-a-web-application

Answer (score 1):

adapted from: http://kennyshu.blogspot.com/2009/05/javascript-get-clients-timezone.html

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
  var gmtOffset
  function timezone()  
  {  
    var localTime = new Date();  
    //this one will give you the GMT offset  
    gmtOffset = localTime.getTimezoneOffset()/60 * (-1);  
  }  
  </script>
```

then post back the variable gmtOffset to your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can get their ip and look it up via a web service or a database, of which I'm sure someone will reply with, or has already replied with in the duplicate question. :-)