# How to get location based time?

Tags: php, javascript

i am working on javascript which displays time based on location, that is if a user logs on from china it should display their local time or a user from india it should display their code.No matter what, i am not able to get the code.pls someone help.

Comment: javascript is a client side language.. so it is based on the local settings of the user.. so please provide more details about your problem

Comment: just came across this code **new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/60;**                   lets see if this works properly

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://www.mtdev.com/2002/06/use-php-and-javascript-to-display-local-time

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630321/how-do-you-retrieve-the-client-users-time-zone-for-a-web-application and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419808/how-to-get-the-current-time-timezone-of-the-user-visiting-my-website

Answer (score 2):

You can get the users local time in JS with:

```
  var currentTime = new Date()
  var hours = currentTime.getHours()
  var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

  if (minutes < 10)
  minutes = "0" + minutes

  document.write("<b>" + hours + ":" + minutes + " " + "</b>")
```